# Friedmann equations question

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, terminology, space-expansion

Friedmann equations for critical density is:

$$\rho_c = \frac{3H^2}{8\pi G}$$

Is there any other way to write this equation? For example:

$$\rho_c = \frac{3}{8\pi GH^2}$$

I saw the above form on another [website](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=747127), and was wondering if it was right?

I think he used Hubble time instead of Hubble's parameter.

Does this work? Even though it isn't like the original equation of Critical Density?

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): OP's second equation  doesn't seem to accurately reproduce the equation mentioned on the linked website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web site you link is using the expression:

$$ \rho_c = \frac{3}{8\pi G \theta^2} $$

where $\theta$ is the Hubble time and is equal to $1/H$. So your second equation should be:

$$ \rho_c = \frac{3}{8\pi G \theta^2} = \frac{3}{8\pi G \left(1/H\right)^2} = \frac{3H^2}{8\pi G} $$

Comment: So it is true that both forms mentioned are correct and will result in the same answer, after unit conversions?

Comment: ...I don't think this should be an answer, John. Then again, the whole question (as you seem to have interpreted it) is so trivial that I don't think it really deserves anything more than a comment (I already left a couple). Anyways, I interpreted the question as: Are there any more (meaningful) ways to express $\rho_c$? This answer does not actually answer that question.

Comment: @NickI: yes, it's the same equation written in two different ways.

Comment: great!
@Danu yes the question is now answered.